# 2011 Grand Caravan won't start on cold days lately

Tags: starting

Yesterday, Sunday, my 2011 Grand Caravan 3.4 litre basic van did not start, plugged the block heater in at 4pm Saturday because it wouldn't start then. So Sunday I put a heater in the engine compartment and covered the hood to the ground with a poly plastic for 3 hours, I went out it started and I drove it for 10 minutes down the highway, came home, shut it off and it restarted a couple of minutes later. Today block heater was plugged in overnight and went to start it no go. It sounded when it first turned over it was going to, but letting go of the key it stopped and then no restart again.  Any help here, it's -9 out today and yesterday was -6 
 Thanks Robin

Comment: Hi Robin.  When you turn the key to "Start", does it sound as if the engine is cranking as quickly as it normally does or does it sound slow?

Comment: yes it cranks normal and it sounds like it is starting it hesitates back to cranking

Comment: yes it it does and it feels like its starting and then it goes back to cranking mode, when I heated it up yesterday and started it right away

Comment: any other ideas, someone told me to wiggle the gear shift back and forth and that didnt do anyrthing

Comment: Please explain "back to cranking mode".  Do you mean when you turn the key to start, the engine cranks quickly and then sounds like it's going to actually start, then gives up sounding that way and goes back to only cranking?

Comment: correct you got it Mike just as im about to let go of the key or strat to let go

Comment: What engine do you have? (Please edit the original question with that info)

Comment: its a 3.4 litre 2011, and the van is basic, no bells and whistles

Comment: You're cold cranking amps might be too low to start your vehicle, have you checked them, you could have a good battery voltage but bad cranking amps

Comment: lots of power, u would not think at all it wont start, everything sounds good, strong cranking, after I heated the engine compartment yesterday it sounded the same as if it was not going to start only it started

Comment: I dont have anyone to try and start so I can read my volt meter checking for amp droppage

Comment: what would heating the engine with 105,000 Km and has never gave a problem on 25,000 Km since I bought it, battery was new 2016 and Van came from dealer trade in this is the first time cold start has been a problem, it started last year -40c, I need to know where to look before I take it to the local shop here Canora Saskatchewan

Answer (score 1):

I would check the MAF, and the intake air temp sensor and the coolant temp sensor not the one that feeds to the guage.

If you can get a vehicle code scanner or barrow one. Make sure you check out the live data on those sensors. If the sensor is bad it will show a unrealistic temp for the conditions. Like if the engine is cold and it reads 100deg or if you know the temp outside and the engine is room temp and it is reading more than 7 degrees off in either direction use reason. The MAF or MAP signal should be stable and not jumping all over while not cranking viewing in graphing mode is easier. MAF should still be showing a reading that is not 0 volts and not higher than .5 when engine is stopped.